# Is there a special procedure for preparing a new but very old stock engine?

Tags: engine, oil, timing-belt, valve

I have a 1979 Austin morris (leyland,freight rover) Sherpa campervan 1979 model 230 with a "17v" "o" series engine 1.7 litre. I am soon to replace the engine with a new old stock (30 years old) that has been stored quite well for 28 years but the last 2 years outside under cover of a tarpaulin.

Does anyone know if there's a procedure for engine preparation before starting her up to ensure a good and healthy start in life? I'm particularly concerned with pre-oiling and damage limitation to rubber valve stem seals. Rubber belts.

Comment: After 3 decades the seals and gaskets will almost certainly degraded, are you planning to replace them?

Comment: I would do what I always do before a first time start and remove all the plugs and spin the engine over without fuel to push oil around the engine - and watch for the oil coming into the camshaft / valve area.

Comment: I'd be concerned about how it was stored and whether or not any rust has formed on the bearings or the cylinder walls.  If this were my project, I'd open it up and inspect it closely.  You likely spent a lot of money on this NOS engine and the last thing you want to do is ruin it the first time the crankshaft spins.

Comment: @Solar Mike Yes, that sounds like a plan. Do you think there's any merit in pan heating the oil before it goes in? I remember you saying you had experience with these engines - any chance you could give your opinion on the other 2 comments?

Comment: @jwh20 Thanks. Do you think that some slight surface rust would just disintegrate or could it actually do some real damage. I got it for about £550 2, maybe 3 years ago on the bay.

Comment: @GdD erhh! No!   I was a little concerned about the rubbers but I hadn't given the gaskets a thought. I figure if the last cylinder head gasket lasted 35 years (blew due to water corrosion on aluminium head, 80,000 miles) . then would be OK.  what do you think?

Comment: @MichaelSherpa  When it comes to bearing and cylinder wall clearances, there is no such thing as "slight"surface rust.